# How to search web for patents only?

Tags: literature-search, patents

How can a search be made at google-scholars, Scopus etc for only patents?

I want to search patents on a given topic or a set of keywords, but the results mostly include papers. Where I have to scan through all the results manually to reach a patent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To search for patents only, [Google Patent Search](http://www.google.com/patents/), rather than Google Scholar, is the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 6):

European Patent Office has a really nice tool called [Espacenet](http://worldwide.espacenet.com/advancedSearch?locale=en_EP), which allows you to make worldwide searches. I have linked the advanced search option, but there are simpler search forms as well.